# Increase magnifying glass Icon inside the input type="search" element

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

> Hello, how can i increase the "size" of the magnifying glass Icon
>   inside the input type="search" element. I am using **jQueryMobile**.

I tried this so far:

```
.ui-input-text input, .ui-input-search input{
    font-size: 24px !important;
    height: 60px !important;
}

.ui-icon-search:after{
    font-size: 300px !important;
    width: 200px !important; 
}
```

My  [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1417fjt9/).
Unfortunately i couldnt find more information even after using the browser Inspector.

Comment: It's a background image, that's why font-size won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector (`.ui-input-search:after` is right) was wrong and it's a background-image not a font icon, so font-size won't have an effect on the displayed magnifying icon.

The following should give you an idea how it works:

```
.ui-input-search:after{
    display: block;
    width: 30px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

2 things wrong with the code

1) The magnifying glass is not a text but an image, so you cant obviously increase the `font-size` of it nor the width or height. You need to replace the image with a bigger one OR control it using `background-size` then increasing the width & height to match the background-size.

```
.ui-input-search:after{
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

2) You are trying to control that icon using `.ui-icon-search:after` which is wrong. The `:after` is on `.ui-input-search:after`.

Answer (score 1):

As it's a background image, so increasing font-size won't make any change. Instead -

First make `background-size` bigger like:

```
.ui-alt-icon.ui-icon-search::after, .ui-alt-icon .ui-icon-search::after, .ui-input-search::after {
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

Then according to that `background-size` you can increase the `element`'s `height`, `width` like:

```
.ui-input-search::after{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

See the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1417fjt9/1/